# Android: как лучше сделать базу данных в приложении?

Tags: android, sql, база-данных

Я только недавно начал изучать Андроид-разработку, поэтому вопросы могут показаться глупыми.

Разрабатываю Android приложение, и настало время для подключения БД. Требуется сделать регистрацию пользователей, и хранить другие множества данных (например, список компаний, который постоянно обновляется).

Всего у меня на уме было 3 варианта:

1. Использовать SQLite (локальное хранилище) - **не подходит** (не буду же я хранить данные всех пользователей и компаний локально на устройстве каждого пользователя? <strike>получается уже своего рода блокчейн</strike>)
2. Использовать Firebase, т.к. насколько я понял это одно из (лучших?) популярных решений - **не подходит**, т.к. оплата Firebase недоступна из России без танцев с бубном
3. Использовать базу данных на удаленном сервере

Если я все правильно понял, из всех вариантов остается только третий - и тут возникают проблемы.

1. Информации о том, как подключить к приложению БД достаточно мало.
2. Нужно использовать веб сервисы, т.к. работать с базой прямо из приложения небезопасно (и еще много причин почему)
3. Нужно писать все запросы вручную на голом SQL?

Подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю всю ситуацию? Может существует более простой путь для использования внешней БД на Android?

*В тех же приложениях на Spring разработчику вообще не приходится думать об организации БД (до какого-то времени), т.к. фреймворк берет всю работу на себя.*

Comment: Так и пишите сервер на Spring, наружу выставьте REST или GraphQL API и дергайте его из мобильного приложения.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja хм, не подумал об этом. Но ни слишком ли громоздко это получится для одного приложения? Помимо разработки самого приложения, еще и сервер на Spring писать

Comment: @Rubix327, таков путь) На самом деле предложенный выше способ - оптимален - он широко распространён, куча информации и примеров. Firebase - та ещё хрень. Реальном меньше времени на свой сервер потратите)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, понял, спасибо за ответ) 
оффтоп: А, если не затруднит, не могли бы вкратце рассказать почему Firebase - "хрень"? Просто интересно.

Comment: @Rubix327, помимо ограничений бесплатного использования она сильно обрезана в фичах, привычных. для реляционных БД. Например нет возможности запустить простой поиск, сложнее проектировать схему, т.к. нет связей между несуществующими таблицами etc. Т.е. надо быть крайне опытным спецом именно на этой БД чтобы понимать в каких случаях её вообще можно использовать

Answer (score 2):

В большинстве случаев используется классическая трёхзвенная архитектура:

1. БД. Одна, хранится на вашем сервере, доступ извне закрыт.
2. Приложение сервер. Запущено на вашем сервере. Может быть один экземпляр или несколько, если нужно обслуживать много подключений. Предоставляет свой API в сеть. Принимает запросы (вызовы методов API) по сети, обрабатывает их внутри себя, обращается к БД, отдаёт клиенту ответ по той же сети.
3. Приложение клиент. Запущено на устройстве клиента. Обрабатывает пользовательский ввод, вызывает API, принимает ответные данные и выводит их пользователю.

Некоторые данные, которые часто нужны клиенту и редко меняются можно сохранить у пользователя локально (SQLite). В API необходимо предусмотреть метод закачки этих данных клиенту. Желательно также предусмотреть возможность проверки актуальности этих данных и возможность получить только изменения, а не всё.